# Twilio, detect if other side picks up?

Tags: ios, twilio

I'm writing a Twilio iOS app and have a question about the lifecycle of calls: If i start a call (using `TCDevice connect:delegate:`) I'd like to know if the call have been picked up by the other side. I've found `TCConnectionDelegate connectionDidDisconnect:` to track that a call *hasn't* been picked up, but is there anything similar to detect if a call *has* been picked up?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio evangelist here.

So, lets start by clarifying what your set up is and make sure I understand the specific question you are asking.

It sounds like you are using the `<Dial>` verb to connect an instance of Twilio Client to another endpoint (PSTN, SIP, Client?).  If that is the case then whats really under the covers is you have a phone call with two legs.  The first leg connects your app to Twilio via Twilio Client.  The second leg connects Twilio with an endpoint (PSTN, SIP, Client) via the `<Dial>` verb.

It sounds like you are asking how to know if the second leg is answered or not.

If I have the question correct, unfortunately there isn't really a way to find this out directly from the Twilio Client SDK, but you can do it from a server-side app, then relay the result to your iOS app.

The `<Dial>` verb includes an attribute named [*action*](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon#attributes-action) which lets you specify a web application URL for Twilio to request when the the second leg call ends.  That request includes a parameter named [DialCallStatus](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon#attributes-action-parameters) which will tell you why the called ended, including if there was no answer.

```
<Dial action="http://www.example.com/callstatus">
    <Number>+15555555555</Number>
</Dial>
```

Once your web application knows the DialCallStatus, if you want to relay it back to your iOS app you can use iOS's push notifications, or you can look at using something like [Pusher](http://pusher.com/), which may be a more light-weight way to send the notification.

Comment: Hi Devin, is there a way to know when the call is actually picked up? b/c as far as I've seen, you don't receive a notification for it so you can't really tell if it's ringing or the other party picked it up, right? you only get notifications for errors and for complete (which means that the call has ended). Thanks!

Comment: There really isn't a good way to have Twilio tell you specifically that a <Dial>'ed call has been answered while that call is in progress.  If you know the number you are dialing you could use the Calls resource of the REST API to try to locate the <Dial>'ed call and check its CallStatus property.  Not ideal though.  Maybe if I knew a bit more about what your scenario is I could help find a better solution for you.

Comment: I'm currently letting our sales people establish calls to our customers. They may connect them to other numbers (I'm using conferences) and everything works great. I keep them updated via websockets so that it's almost real time. But... I'd like to be able to tell them "hey, this caller just picked up the phone" as soon as they do. I'd hate to have to poll your API to see when that happens... so, the only alternative has been using Asterisk and calling a macro on the Dial, but would love to keep that on twilio's side. Ideally, twilio would invoke the callback with a new status (connected)